# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2k+1)^n \pi^n}{n !}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have some problems in evaluating the following series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2k+1)^n \pi^n}{n !},$$
where $k$ is an integer. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know the power series of $e^x$?

Comment: Yes, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Thank you!

Comment: Glad you worked it out. [We encourage answering your own question if you can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Comment: Try a bonus question if you want, $$\sum_{k = 0}^ \infty \sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{(-2k+1)^n{\pi}^n}{n!}$$

Comment: The bonus question equals $\sum_{k = 0}^ {\infty} e^{(-2k+1)\pi}=e^{\pi}\sum_{k = 0}^ {\infty}e^{(-2\pi)k}=e^{\pi} \frac{1}{1-e^{(-2\pi)}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) $e^x=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. It means that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2k+1)^n \pi^n}{n !}=e^{(-2k+1)\pi}$